# How make Dependency Tree with phpDocumentor and Graphviz?

Tags: php, graphviz, diagram, phpdoc

I have both phpDocumentor and Graphviz installed. When I run phpdoc, all it creates is a "Class Hierarchy" image, but doesn't use any of the `@uses` tags to create a Dependency Tree. How do I get it to create that?

For example, my class `MainClass` instantiates and uses the `DBHandler` class. So I'd like a diagram that shows that. How can i use phpDocumentor to create that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpDocumentor2 does not provide such a graph based on the `@uses` tags.  It really only shows inheritance and implements relationships.